# PHP - Search array of sentences for search term(s)?

Tags: php, arrays, search, levenshtein-distance

So, suppose I have a simple array of sentences. What would be the best way to search it based on user input, and return the closest match?

The Levenshtein functions seem promising, but I don't think I want to use them. User input may be as simple as `highest mountain`, in which case I'd want to search for the sentence in the array that has `highest mountain`. If that exact phrase does not exist, then I'd want to search for the sentence that has `highest` AND `mountain`, but not back-to-back, and so on. The Levenshtein functions work on a per-character basis, but what I really need is a per-word basis.

Of course, to some degree, Levenshtein functions may still be useful, as I'd also want to take into account the possibility of the sentence containing the phrase `highest mountains` (notice the S) or similar.

What do you suggest? Are there any systems for PHP that do this that already exist? Would Levenshtein functions alone be an adequate solution? Is there a word-based Levenshtein function that I don't know about?

Thanks!

**EDIT** - I have considered both MySQL fulltext search, and have also considered the possibility of breaking both A) input and B) each sentence into separate arrays of words, and then compared that way, using Levenshtein functions to account for variations in words. (color, colour, colors, etc) However, I am concerned that this method, though possibly clever, may be computationally taxing.

Comment: Why not do it in the DB ? What is the source of your data ?

Comment: This is suited more toward a fulltext search in the database, than something hand-built in PHP.

Comment: I am parsing Wikipedia articles into sentences. If it would be quicker to store these in a database, fulltext search, and then delete those entries from the database, I am open to that solution, though I can't imagine it being very efficient.

Comment: Are you using http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/ ? There is a Lucene library in it, never used it but it seems right if you want to keep away from DB!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html

> Zend_Search_Lucene offers a HTML parsing feature. Documents can be created directly from a HTML file or string:

```
$doc = Zend_Search_Lucene_Document_Html::loadHTML($htmlString);
$index->addDocument($doc);
```

Comment: Hmm. This may work, but it looks moderately complicated. I'll do some research. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Thanks for the research request, Lucene is well known in the Java world and I will consider this for PHP from now on =)

Comment: I've used Zend Lucene.  It's not a great port.  Performance was in some cases several orders of magnitude worse than Java Lucene (5 ms queries became 5 second queries in Zend Lucene), and the feature set was incomplete.

Comment: I see. How much data were you querying ?

Answer (score 1):

As I am not a fan of writing code for you, I would normally ask you what you have tried first.  However, I was currently stuck on something, so took a break to write this:

```
$results=array();
foreach($array as $sentence){
    if(stripos($sentence,$searchterm)!==false)
        $results[]=$sentence;
}
if(count($results)==0){
    $wordlist=explode(" ",$searchterm);
    foreach($wordlist as $word){
        foreach($array as $sentence){
            if(stripos($sentence,$word)!==false)
                $results[]=$sentence;
        }
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

This will search an array of sentences for terms exactly.  It will not find a result if you typed in "microsift" and the sentence had the word "Microsoft".  It is case insensitive, so it should work better.  If no results are found using the full term, it is broken up and searched by word.  Hope this at least points you to a starting place.

Comment: Thanks! What I'm looking for is probably a bit more complicated than just this (it'll need to be a fuzzy search IN ADDITION to a full word-based search) but I appreciate the idea!

Answer (score 0):

There are not built-in functions for PHP to do this. This is because what you are asking for involves search relevance, related terms, iterative searching, and many more complex operations that need to mimic human logic in searching. You can try looking for PHP-based search classes, although the ones that I know are database search engines rather than array search classes. Making your own is prohibitively complex.